# Parametric Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matlab, multiplication, parametric-equations

Does matlab supports such multiplication??
[image]
I searched a lot and find these

```
>> X = @(a1,a2,a3,a4)[a1 a2;a3 a4];
>> Y = @(b1,b2,b3,b4)[b1 b2;b3 b4];
>> % Something like ==> X*Y
```

But this just solves an equation with "value" and does not solve parametric for me. Does matlab support such a multiplication?

Comment: That's good old matrix multiplication, which is of course supported by Matlab. What do you mean with "solve" and "parametric"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe more of a long comment than an answer, but are you looking for symbolic variables? It requires the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

Example:

```
clc
clear

syms a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3 b4

A = [a1 a2;a3 a4]
B = [b1 b2;b3 b4]

C = (A*B)

C =

[ a1*b1 + a2*b3, a1*b2 + a2*b4]
[ a3*b1 + a4*b3, a3*b2 + a4*b4]
```

Is this what you mean by "parametric matrix"?

Comment: awesome then glad to help